# I found the answer in which it was suggested to use CallableStatementCreator() method for calling the function which I have created in postgresql,

Tags: spring, postgresql, jdbc

I have created the following function in Postgresql:-

```
CREATE function getrecord1 (in_id INTEGER, OUT out_name character varying(20), 
                            OUT out_age Integer)
as
    $$SELECT name, age from finalstud where id=in_id$$
LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE
COST 100;
```

In Spring, the following is the code of my class in which in am calling the above function:-

```
public class StudentJDBCTemplate implements StudentDao {
    private DataSource dataSource;
    private SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall;

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource){ //`enter code here`
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
        this.jdbcCall =  new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource)
                                 .withFunctionName("getrecord1");
    }

    public Student getStudent(Integer id) {
          SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource()
                                                  .addValue("in_id", id);
          Map<String, Object> out = jdbcCall.execute(in);
          System.out.println("printing map values:"+out.values());
          Student student = new Student();
          student.setID(id);
          student.setName((String) out.get("out_name"));
          student.setAge((Integer) out.get("out_age"));
          return student;
    }
}
```

But when i am executing it, it gives the following exception:-

```
Dec 10, 2013 6:08:42 PM  
     org.springframework.jdbc.core.metadata.CallMetaDataContext
matchInParameterValuesWithCallParameters 
WARNING: Unable to locate the corresponding parameter value for '$1' within 
the parameter values provided: [in_id]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.dao
   .InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Required input parameter '$1' 
   is missing
```

Comment: You haven't specified any attributes/parameter on your function call. So nothing goes in, nothing comes out. You need to specify your in/out parameters when constructing the `SimpleJdbcCall`.